# Constructing proper promises in node using a+

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a function:

```
calculateDemand(skills) {
    let average = 0;
    let demandArray = [];
    // logic to make demandArray equal something 
    Promise.resolve(demandArray);
}
```

which I call inside another function here

```
            this.calculateDemand(skills).then((demandArray) => {
                 console.log(demandArray);
            })
```

I get an error saying I am calling then on undefined. I have been reading documentation on promisejs.org on A+ implementation of Promises, but I am not sure how to solve this simple use case. Could someone provide an example of how I would correct this code?

Before this, I was constructing new promises everytime using the `constructor anti-pattern`, so I am looking for best-practice.

Comment: You need to return the `Promise`

Comment: Do you realize that there's no reason to use a promise at all if you're not doing an asynchronous operation?

Comment: yes, this is asynchronous. it is hard to see without the full context of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your last line to read `return Promise.resolve(demandArray);` in `calculateDemand()`